# localhost:8050 Splash in browser is loading different html than the one used in my Scrapy script

Tags: web, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

When I use Splash by going to localhost:8050 in my browser it loads different html than the one in my Scrapy script.  Below is the Lua script (the one used in localhost:8050) that loads the HTML I want.

```
function main(splash, args)
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(20))
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
```

Here is the code from my Scrapy script that is not loading the HTML I want:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
                            endpoint='render.html',
                            args={'wait': 20},
                            )
```

I am passing the same URL for both.  Any suggestions?

Note I am getting this error but the script appears to still run:

```
ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function to_native_str. Use to_unicode instead.
```

Idk why I have been getting so frustrated with Splash but it seems like when I do things with Selenium it just works but I am always having problems with Splash.  I clearly have some knowledge gaps that I need to fill.

EDIT:
Changes so it uses Lua script:

```
LUA_SCRIPT = """
function main(splash, args)
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(20))
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
"""

SCRAPY_CRAWLER_NAME = 'oddschecker'
SCRAPY_SPLASH_ENDPOINT = 'render.html'
SCRAPY_ARGS = {
    'lua_source': LUA_SCRIPT

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        print(url)
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
                            endpoint='execute',
                            args=SCRAPY_ARGS,
                            )
```

settings.py file:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
   'surefirebetting.middlewares.SurefirebettingSpiderMiddleware': 543,
}

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
    'surefirebetting.middlewares.SurefirebettingDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
}

SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

Comment: that is not an error, it's only a warning, also you are not passing the lua script in the `request`

Comment: Yeah I know I am not passing it in but that splash request should get me the same result as the Lua Script correct?

Comment: yes, you just need to pass it in the request

Comment: Even when I pass the Lua script into the Splash Request it doesn't give me the same HTML that I get when using the same Lua script at localhost:8050.  I am not sure what it is causing this when I am using the same script.

Comment: I feel like it has to something in my Scrapy settings.py otherwise, the code should work exactly the same.

Comment: can you show how you pass it in the requests, I assume you are using the docker splash on 8050, make sure to enable it in the middleware

Comment: I posted what I have above as an edit, yes I am using docker splash.  Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: Do you have any advice?

Comment: I can't help because this isn't reproducible code, I can tell you the logic is correct

Comment: Rip I don't get it man.

Comment: when run the docker splash you should see your requests there, see if you get any errors or that you are indeed making the requests

Comment: All status 200.  There is nothing to indicate that anything wrong is happening when I check docker it is sending the exact requests I want and getting html.  Just not the html I want.  It's like it's pulling all of the html except for an frame of javascript in the middle.  Which is fine but I don't understand why it would work fine in localhost:8050 in my browser but not my script.  If you disable private mode on docker startup that obviously translates to the script as well correct?  I just have no idea.  I wish this website had an API lol

Comment: When I disable Javascript in chrome dev tools I realize it's loading everything except the javascript right in the middle of the page.